# Setting two modules as one console application

Tags: .net, vb.net

I made two console application, both calculates data for a 3D CAD program. One calculates normal data and the other Calculates the same data in Logarithmic form.
Now i want to have both in one console application. The users needs to choose, in the command window, if they want to use the normal one or the logarithmic one.
I tried this putting both in a different sub, and using a main sub like the following:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Console.Write("Logarithmic? (yes/no):")
        While Console.ReadLine = "no"
            Call normal()
        End While
        While Console.ReadLine = "yes"
            Call log()
        End While
    End Sub
```

this didn't work because it only caled the first sub.
Or is there a way i can call a different module or something?

Comment: What language in .net is this? Also your while loops should be if conditions

Comment: Its version 2003, i know its old but IT doesn't want to install any newer or express versions.

Comment: I tried it with the if condition, but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two separate loops, meaning it only checks for "no" in the first loop, and only checks for "yes" in the second; assuming you **want** to loop, the approach should be (pseudo-code)

```
keepGoing = true;
while(keepGoing)
   line = ReadLine
   switch(line)
       case "no"
           normal();
       case "yes"
           log()
       default
           keepGoing = false
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. OKay i tried that but couldnt get it working. What do you mean with keepgoing?